# wxpython Prevent Ctrl+Enter from changing the focus

Tags: python, wxpython

I have two wxListCtrl and want to process the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> keyboard event without letting wx change the focus to the other ListCtrl.

I have event handlers for  wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, wx.EVT_KEY_UP, wx.EVT_CHAR and KillFocus, but KillFocus is always called first, then the focus changes and the the keyboard handlers are called for the wrong ListCtrl.

Is there a way to prevent wx from changing the focus, when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea if this will work, but who knows!

```
    ac = [(wx.ACCEL_CTRL, wx.WXK_RETURN, wx.NewId())]
    tbl = wx.AcceleratorTable(ac)
    list.SetAcceleratorTable(tbl)  # should overwrite its bindings?
```

or also try EVT_CHAR_HOOK